# Roots of the XXZ Bethe Ansatz equation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The XXZ spin chain [Bethe Ansatz equations](http://www.itp.phys.ethz.ch/research/qftstrings/archive/13FSInt/Problems2.pdf) are a complicated system of rational function equation:

\[  \left(\frac{\lambda_j + i/2}{\lambda_j - i/2}  \right)^N = \prod_{l=1, l \neq j}^M \frac{\lambda_j - \lambda_l + i}{\lambda_j - \lambda_l - i}  \]

Generically, since there are M equations and M unknowns generically we could say the solutions in $\lambda$ are a discrete set of points.

Is there any other logic to their roots besides the fact that they solve these equations ?

---

Spin chains have to do with the raising and lowering operators in the 2-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$ :
\[\left.\begin{array}{cccc} S^+ : & |\uparrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & 0 \\
& |\downarrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & |\uparrow  \rangle \\ \hline 
S^- : & |\uparrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & |\downarrow  \rangle \\
& |\downarrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & 0   \\ \hline
 \\ 
S^z : & |\uparrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & \tfrac{1}{2}|\uparrow \rangle \\
& |\downarrow  \rangle & \mapsto  & \tfrac{1}{2}|\downarrow  \rangle \end{array}\right.
\]

The Hamiltonian acts on a tensor product of $SU(2)$ representations $V^{\otimes M}$.

\[ \mathcal{H} = - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^M \bigg[ \sigma_n^x \sigma_{n+1}^x 
+ \sigma_n^y \sigma_{n+1}^y  + \Delta \sigma_n^z \sigma_{n+1}^z\bigg] \]

Various values of $\Delta$ have different interpretations.  Since $[\mathcal{H}, S^z] = 0$ we can diagonalize in terms of the $\uparrow, \downarrow$ states.  The Bethe Ansatz equations are the eigenvalue equations for $\mathcal{H}$ in this basis.

None of this tells you how to *solve* the eigenvalue equations, here they are.

Comment: Sorry, S are sigmas ? Also Bethe eq. are not exactly for eigenvalues, eigenvalues can be expressed via them...

Comment: If I read correctly $S^\pm  = \sigma^x \pm i \sigma^y, S^z = \sigma^z$.  The [raising-lowering operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Creation_and_annihilation_operators_for_reaction-diffusion_equations), being slightly different from [Pauli spin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Answer (score 3):

The Bethe equations and Bethe ansatz are the central tools to study quantum integrable systems and  there are thousands papers devoted to them. I cannot pretend to know substantial part of this research, so let me write some remarks which I am aware of.

You ask  "... is there **logic** to their roots ... "

Yes, there is some logic - the keyword is "string hypothesis" (it is NOT related to string theory).

Let me quote from [String hypothesis for gl(n|m) spin chains: a particle/hole democracy](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3454)
Section 3.1 page 10.

> Suppose that N is large and some Bethe root $\lambda_n$ has a positive
> imaginary part. Then the l.h.s of (26) is exponentially
> large with N. To achieve this large value on the r.h.s. there should
> be another Bethe root $\lambda_n′ ∼ \lambda_n − i$, with the help of which the pole in
> the r.h.s. is created. Repeating the same arguments for $\lambda_n′$ and using
> the reality of solution of the Bethe Ansatz [36], we conclude that the
> Bethe roots are organized in the complexes of the type:

$\lambda_k = \lambda_0 + ik, ~~ k= -(s-1)/2, -(s-3)/2, ..., +(s-1)/2. $

> where s is an integer. These complexes are called **s-strings**.
>
> String
> hypothesis in its strong form states that all solutions of the Bethe
> Ansatz equations can be represented as a collection of strings, and
> that $\lambda_k$ are approximated by $\lambda_0 + ik$ values with exponential in N
> precision. In its strong form the string hypothesis is wrong. However
> there is an evidence that its weaker version is correct if the proper
> thermodynamic limit is taken. The weaker version states that most of
> the Bethe roots are organized into strings with exponential in N
> precision, and that the fraction of solutions which signiﬁcantly diﬀer
> from (27) decreases to 0 when N → ∞. We discuss in more details
> applicability of the string hypothesis in appendix A.